# How to get the set of values defined with PROPERTY STRINGS

Tags: cmake

CMake allows constraining a cache entry to a set of values. e.g. see
[this link](http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/82), citing:

```
set(BaseName "binary" CACHE STRING "BaseName chosen by the user at CMake configure time")
set_property(CACHE BaseName PROPERTY STRINGS binary octal decimal hexadecimal)
```

Now cmake-gui knows to present a drop-down combo box for editing the "BaseName" cache entry.

The question is how to 'get' the set of values defined with `PROPERTY STRINGS`, in order to validate the user's (potentially wrong) input from the command line:

```
cmake -DBaseName:STRING=ValueNotInList -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like there's [`set_property()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/set_property.html), there's also [`get_property()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/get_property.html):

```
get_property(res CACHE BaseName PROPERTY STRINGS)
```

This sets the variables `res` to the content of the property.

Comment: @ddb If an answer solves your problem, you should consider marking it as the accepted answer (max 1 per question) using the green check mark. That marks the question as solved, gives both you and the answerer some reputation, and is generally [how Stack Overflow works](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).